# How do I update my instance variables in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I want the color of the circle to change as the stepper is clicked.  I believe the problem is that I am using an instance of the class.

this is my first file:

> class ViewController: UIViewController {
>
> ```
> @IBOutlet var redValue: UILabel!
> @IBOutlet var greenValue: UILabel!
> @IBOutlet var blueValue: UILabel!
>
> @IBOutlet var redStepper: UIStepper!
> @IBOutlet var greenStepper: UIStepper!
> @IBOutlet var blueStepper: UIStepper!
>
> var redd = 0.0;
> var greenn = 0.0;
> var bluee = 0.0;
>
> @IBAction func redChange(sender: UIStepper)
> {
>     redValue.text = Int(sender.value).description;
>     redd = sender.value;
> }
> @IBAction func greenChange(sender: UIStepper)
> {
>     greenValue.text = Int(sender.value).description;
>     greenn = sender.value;
> }
> @IBAction func blueChange(sender: UIStepper)
> {
>     blueValue.text = Int(sender.value).description;
>     bluee = sender.value;
> }
> ```
>
> }

this is my second file:

> class UIView1: UIView {
>
> ```
> var colors = ViewController();
>
> required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
> {
>     super.init(coder: aDecoder)
> }
>
> override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)
> { 
>     let circle2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: -25.0, y: 10.0, width: 100.0, height:100.0))
>     circle2.layer.cornerRadius = 50.0
>     let startingColor2 = UIColor(red: (CGFloat(colors.redd)/255), 
>            green: (CGFloat(colors.greenn))/255, blue: (CGFloat(colors.bluee))/255, alpha: 1.0)
>     circle2.backgroundColor = startingColor2;
>     addSubview(circle2);    
> }
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

There could be various connectivity issues, since we cannot see that code/IB.  However, I suspect minimally you are missing the call to inform the view it needs to redraw itself because underlying values have changed.

```
self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
```

Here's the entire playground I used to experiment, with various mods to your code. Inspect the last copy to see the change. Note: the UI elements aren't actually created, I simulate a slick after manually setting the `UIStepper.value`.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var redValue: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var greenValue: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var blueValue: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var redStepper: UIStepper!
    @IBOutlet var greenStepper: UIStepper!
    @IBOutlet var blueStepper: UIStepper!

    var redd = 100.0;
    var greenn = 100.0;
    var bluee = 100.0;

    @IBAction func redChange(sender: UIStepper)
    {
        redValue?.text = Int(sender.value).description
        redd = sender.value
        self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
    @IBAction func greenChange(sender: UIStepper)
    {
        greenValue.text = Int(sender.value).description
        greenn = sender.value
    }
    @IBAction func blueChange(sender: UIStepper)
    {
        blueValue.text = Int(sender.value).description
        bluee = sender.value
    }
}


class UIView1: UIView {

    var colors = ViewController()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)
    {
        let circle2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: -25.0, y: 10.0, width: 100.0, height:100.0))
        circle2.layer.cornerRadius = 50.0
        let startingColor2 = UIColor(red: CGFloat(colors.redd/255.0),
            green: (CGFloat(colors.greenn))/255,
            blue: (CGFloat(colors.bluee))/255,
            alpha: 1.0)
        circle2.backgroundColor = startingColor2;
        addSubview(circle2);    
    }
}

let v = UIView1(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,400, 240))
v.colors.view = v

let rstepper = UIStepper(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,300,50))
rstepper.maximumValue = 255.0
rstepper.value = 240.0
v.colors.redChange(rstepper)


// inspect the view now:
v
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is indeed the problem.

```
 var colors = ViewController()
```

creates a new instance that isn't related to the instance of the view controller that contains your view.  Reference to colors.redd within your view's drawrect code isn't reaching the active view controller.

The relationship should be in the other direction.  Your view controller is expected to know the instance of your custom view (through an outlet normally) and it should be setting your view's color properties or at least work as a kind of delegate for it.